# Concatenate word of a column with every other words from other column python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Here is the dataset

```
pd.DataFrame({'Word':['Iron','copper','nickel'],'Sentence':['An Apple a day','Roses are red','Skies are blue']})
```

I'm trying to concatenate one word with every other word and append that into a new column such that my output will look like

```
     Word        Sentence                         New_Sentence
0    Iron  An Apple a day   An_Iron Apple_Iron a_Iron day_Iron
1  copper   Roses are red   Roses_copper are_copper red_copper
2  nickel  Skies are blue  skies_nickel are_nickel blue_nickel
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can add some code, what you try for prevent downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get each word in `Sentence` by `split` and add `Word` with `f-string`s:

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join(f"{y}_{x['Word']}" for y in x['Sentence'].split())
df['New_Sentence'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
     Word        Sentence                         New_Sentence
0    Iron  An Apple a day   An_Iron Apple_Iron a_Iron day_Iron
1  copper   Roses are red   Roses_copper are_copper red_copper
2  nickel  Skies are blue  Skies_nickel are_nickel blue_nickel
```

Or use list comprehension with `zip`:

```
zipped = zip(df['Word'], df['Sentence'])
df['New_Sentence'] = [' '.join(f"{y}_{a}" for y in b.split()) for a, b in zipped]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> df['New_Sentence'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(['_'.join(i) for i in [(s, x['Word'])
                                 for s in x['Sentence'].split()]]), axis=1)

>>> df

     Word        Sentence                         New_Sentence
0    Iron  An Apple a day   An_Iron Apple_Iron a_Iron day_Iron
1  copper   Roses are red   Roses_copper are_copper red_copper
2  nickel  Skies are blue  Skies_nickel are_nickel blue_nickel
```